# Thread.Abort causing deadlock in catch{} statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch, deadlock, thread-abort

I have a set of threaded classes that print different types of documents. The classes use inheritance to share common code. The class constructor requires file name and printer name arguments. A `Print()` method creates a new worker thread, waits for the worker thread to complete using `Thread.Join(timeout)` and calls `Thread.Abort()` on the worker thread if the `Join` times out. The worker thread starts an application that can open the specified file, causes the file to be sent to printer synchronously (usually using application's Print method) and exits. The worker thread's code is wrapped in a `try{} ... catch{}` block to deal with any unforeseen crashes of the external application. The catch block contains minimal cleanup and logging.

```
    internal static FilePackage TryPrintDocumentToPdf(string Filename)
    {
                .....

                Logging.Log("Printing this file using PowerPoint.", Logging.LogLevel.Debug);
                printableFormat = true;

                fc = new FileCollector(Email2Pdf.Settings.Printer.PdfAttachmentCollectDirectoryObj, FileCollector.CollectMethods.FileCount | FileCollector.CollectMethods.FilesNotInUse | FileCollector.CollectMethods.ProcessExit);
                fc.FileCount = 1;
                fc.ProcessNames = new string[] { OfficePowerPointExe, Email2Pdf.Settings.Printer.PrinterExe };
                fc.Prepare();

                using (PowerPointPrinter printer = new PowerPointPrinter(Filename, Email2Pdf.Settings.Printer.PdfAttachmentPrinter))
                {
                    printer.KillApplicationOnClose = true;
                    printer.Print();
                    printOk = printer.PrintOk;
                }

                .....
    }

    internal abstract class ApplicationPrinter : IDisposable
    {
        protected abstract string applicationName { get; }

        protected string filename;
        protected string printer;

        protected bool workerPrintOk;
        protected bool printOk;
        public bool PrintOk { get { return printOk; } }
        public bool KillApplicationOnClose { get; set; }

        public void Print()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread worker = new System.Threading.Thread(printWorker);
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            worker.Start();

            if (worker.Join(new TimeSpan(0, Email2Pdf.Settings.Printer.FileGenerateTimeOutMins, 0)))
            {
                printOk = workerPrintOk;
            }
            else
            {
                worker.Abort();
                printOk = false;
                Logging.Log("Timed out waiting for " + applicationName + " file " + filename + " to print.", Logging.LogLevel.Error);
            }
        }

        protected abstract void Close();
        protected abstract void printWorker();

        public virtual void Dispose() { Close(); }
    }
    internal class PowerPointPrinter : ApplicationPrinter
    {
        private const string appName = "PowerPoint";
        protected override string applicationName { get { return appName; } }
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application officePowerPoint = null;

        public PowerPointPrinter(string Filename, string Printer)
        {
            filename = Filename;
            printer = Printer;
            this.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void printWorker()
        {
            try
            {
                officePowerPoint = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
                officePowerPoint.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation doc = null;

                doc = officePowerPoint.Presentations.Open(
                    filename,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                doc.PrintOptions.ActivePrinter = printer;
                doc.PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                doc.PrintOptions.OutputType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType.ppPrintOutputSlides;
                doc.PrintOut();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                doc.Close();
                //Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
                doc = null;

                workerPrintOk = true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.Log("Unable to print PowerPoint file " + filename + ". Exception: " + ex.Message, Logging.LogLevel.Error);
                Close();
                workerPrintOk = false;
            }
        }

        protected override void Close()
        {
            try
            {
                if (officePowerPoint != null)
                    officePowerPoint.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(officePowerPoint);
                officePowerPoint = null;
                if (KillApplicationOnClose)
                    Utility.KillProcessesByName(OfficePowerPointExe);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

I found my application non-responsive, with the main thread in a Sleep/Wait/Join at the Thread.Abort() line. I do not recall the status of the worker thread, but the logging that was supposed to be performed in the `catch{}` block did not take place. (I *Attached* to my process with VS2010 after I found it non-responsive).

I refer to the following **Note** from the [Thread.Abort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx):

> The thread that calls Abort might block if the thread that is being
>   aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block,
>   finally block, or constrained execution region. If the thread that
>   calls Abort holds a lock that the aborted thread requires, a deadlock
>   can occur.

I believe I have a dead-locking issue because (1) it does not always happen, and (2) because of the **Note** on MSDN (above).

1. The Note appears to suggest that using `try{} ... catch{}` is **NEVER** safe inside a thread if the thread can be `Abort()`'ed. Is this true?
2. I do not see how I can avoid using `Abort()` in my scenario. Will using `Thread.Interrupt()` instead make any difference?
3. How to I fix the dead-locking issue I have?

BackgroundWorker does not work for me because I do not need progress reporting and, more importantly, it is possible that my worker thread will block indefinitely when it executes third party applications. For the same reason, I cannot *ask* my thread to terminate, but have one option only - to ruthlessly `Abort()` the worker thread.

Comment: Have you considered using a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: You should redesign to avoid use of `Thread.Abort`, killing a thread, instead of politely asking it to end, leads to all sorts of problems such as yours.

Comment: @ChrisO I cannot _ask_ my thread to end if it's blocked doing something outside my control, such as executing a Print() method on an application I did not write. Also, my thread has no loops etc.

Comment: You should design your threads such that they can respond to shutdown requests.

Comment: Your real problem is the timeout.  The thread no doubt is blocking on a low level RPC call, the one that makes the out-of-process call to PowerPoint.  Such a call can't be aborted by Thread.Abort().  No good cure for this but finding out why PowerPoint got stuck.  It might be as simple as it trying to display a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution by making the following changes:

1. Do not call `Thread.Abort()` if we **know** that the worker thread is executing a `catch{}` block (see `protected volatile bool isPrinting` below).
2. Use a separate thread to call `Thread.Abort()` and encourage a context switch with `Sleep(0)` (see `private void AbortPrintWorker()` below).

   ```
   internal abstract class ApplicationPrinter : IDisposable
   {
       protected abstract string applicationName { get; }

       protected string filename;
       protected string printer;

       protected bool workerPrintOk;
       protected bool printOk;
       public bool PrintOk { get { return printOk; } }
       public bool KillApplicationOnClose { get; set; }

       protected System.Threading.Thread worker;
       protected volatile bool isPrinting;

       public void Print()
       {
           worker = new System.Threading.Thread(printWorker);
           DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
           worker.Start();

           if (worker.Join(new TimeSpan(0, Email2Pdf.Settings.Printer.FileGenerateTimeOutMins, 0)))
           {
               printOk = workerPrintOk;
           }
           else
           {
               AbortPrintWorker();
               printOk = false;
               Logging.Log("Timed out waiting for " + applicationName + " file " + filename + " to print.", Logging.LogLevel.Error);
           }
       }
       protected abstract void printWorker();

       public abstract void Dispose();

       private void AbortPrintWorker()
       {
           System.Threading.Thread abortThread = new System.Threading.Thread(abortWorker);
           if (isPrinting)
           {
               abortThread.Start();
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
               abortThread.Join();
           }
           else
           {
               worker.Join();
           }
       }

       private void abortWorker()
       {
           worker.Abort();
           worker.Join();
       }
   }

   internal class PowerPointPrinter : ApplicationPrinter
   {
       private const string appName = "PowerPoint";
       protected override string applicationName { get { return appName; } }
       private Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application officePowerPoint = null;

       public PowerPointPrinter(string Filename, string Printer)
       {
           filename = Filename;
           printer = Printer;
           this.Dispose();
       }

       protected override void printWorker()
       {
           try
           {
               isPrinting = true;

               officePowerPoint = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
               officePowerPoint.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone;

               Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation doc = null;

               doc = officePowerPoint.Presentations.Open(
                   filename,
                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
               doc.PrintOptions.ActivePrinter = printer;
               doc.PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
               doc.PrintOptions.OutputType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType.ppPrintOutputSlides;
               doc.PrintOut();

               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

               doc.Close();
               Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
               doc = null;

               workerPrintOk = true;

               isPrinting = true;
           }
           catch (System.Exception ex)
           {
               isPrinting = false;

               Logging.Log("Unable to print PowerPoint file " + filename + ". Exception: " + ex.Message, Logging.LogLevel.Error);
               workerPrintOk = false;
           }
       }

       public override void Dispose()
       {
           try
           {
               if (officePowerPoint != null)
                   officePowerPoint.Quit();
               Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(officePowerPoint);
               officePowerPoint = null;
               if (KillApplicationOnClose)
                   Utility.KillProcessesByName(OfficePowerPointExe);
           }
           catch { }
       }
   }
   ```

`AbortPrintWorker()` creates a separate thread to call `Abort()` on the worker thread. I believe this deals with the issue highlighted in the **Note** on `Abort()`:

> The thread that calls Abort might block if the thread that is being
>   aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block,
>   finally block, or constrained execution region. If the thread that
>   calls Abort holds a lock that the aborted thread requires, a deadlock
>   can occur.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your mechanism using `Thread.Abort()` is not a good one. In fact, calling `Thread.Abort()` should be avoided.

> The thread that calls Abort might block if the thread that is being
>   aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block,
>   finally block, or constrained execution region. If the thread that
>   calls Abort holds a lock that the aborted thread requires, a deadlock
>   can occur.   [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx).

Instead, use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which supports cancellation, progress reporting (and auto marshalling onto UI thread in completed event).

Comment: BackgroundWorker does not work for me because in my case I may need to ruthlessly kill the thread if it is blocked.

Comment: 1. Why will it block?  2. It supports cancellation. 3. you should not be 'ruthlessly killing' threads for the reason already mentioned.

Comment: @MitchWheat The BackgroundWorker class does support cancellation, but in order for it to work, the worker method has to periodically check whether a cancellation is pending (see [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx)).  If the worker method is blocked by something, it won't be able to check the flag.  I think that is the point that user1110897 is trying to make-- he's saying he's blocked by an outside process so there's no graceful way to support cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are basically remote-controlling the PowerPoint application in order to print a PowerPoint document.  Thus you could be subject to any dialog boxes that the application put up (or tried to put up) on the screen.  If this whole thing is being run in the background (e.g. on a server), there may not be a user to dismiss any such dialogs, so that could explain part of the issue.  My recommendation would be to look into third-party libraries that would allow you to load a PPT file and print it (or convert it to PDF and print that) without having to rely on the PowerPoint application.  Then you wouldn't have to wait on an external app outside your control and you woudln't have to resort to forcefully aborting threads.

Comment: Yes, I am remote-controlling external applications, including PowerPoint, but not only. I have several classes that inherit from ApplicationPrinter and provide implementation for printing different types of files. The application runs un-attended, but not on a web server, and the unexpected dialogs and errors is exactly what I want to handle.